# What time do I have to beat for the crafting skills?

Tags: fantasy-life

In Fantasy Life you play a lot of minigames in order to create items. The time in which you finish crafting the item can alter its properties or give you multiples. What I am looking for is a list of professions that do this (I know Alchemy and Cooking do this at the least) and what their time limits are for which bonuses. For example, if you cook a recipe and still have 15 or 20 seconds left on the clock you will either get a superior or multiple of the recipe you were making. An exact time on that range and what the time limits are for the other skills are what I am after (that was not the time limit on Alchemy to get the same bonuses though it said it would do it)

Edit: Additional info from playing this morning is that the results seem to be both time based and skill based. The results of each action play into it as well as completing it on time. I could often get 3 extra ingots if I got Great! on every step and finished with 12 to 10.5 seconds left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four or five possible results you can get when (successfully) crafting X of an item:

- Top quality (this manifests as X + 1 superior [item]s when cooking/alching and X + 3 [item]s when making a resource item like oak beams)
- Great quality (X superior [item]s or X + 2 [item]s)
- Good quality (X + 1 normal-quality [item]s or X + 1 [item]s)
- Normal [no quality tag]
- If you get the DLC, you can add certain items to make the result item Divine quality which is better than top quality

Unfortunately, there isn't a definite way to determine how to get a certain level of quality every time.  The quality of the craft depends on the difficulty of the item and three things:

- Your skill level in the craft

  - Determined by the tool you are using and your ability points in the major and minor class abilities, e.g. Intelligence and Dexterity for Alchemist.  These can be determined by checking your license and seeing what bonuses you get, e.g. Adept Alchemist gets +6 Intelligence (major) and +3 Dexterity (minor)
- How well you perform while making the craft

  - This is determined by how long you take to finish the craft and/or how many Great!/Nice! ratings you get.  It is difficult to tell if one is more influential than the other.
- Randomness

Sometimes you can perform exactly the same (or better!) and get a worse result, so there's no deterministic way to ensure that you will make a high-quality item.  However, if you notice that you are consistently making a low-quality version of the item you want to produce, you should try to get a better version of the tool you need to make it, or put points in the major/minor abilities for that class the next time you level up.